# Problem with commits search by user in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

From a project, when I try to search for a user's commits (filtering by author), only those that have been merged appear. If there are commits that have only been uploaded to a branch without merge, they do not appear in this search. If I remove the search by author, they do appear.

Image of the search engine used

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. If this is solely about the usage of Gitlab, and you assume that this is a bug, then please report it in Gitlabs bug tracker

Comment: The problem is in the browser attached to the image in my message.
This message is in the commits section of a project.
When you search by user, only the commits that have been merged appear. If you don't use the search, both merge and non-merged commits appear.

I don't know what more information I can give you. I can't find any settings for it.

We are using version 14.4.0.0-ee

Comment: If this is not programming related, please post it to Gitlabs bug tracker

Comment: I posted it. Thank you.

Comment: Yesterday, GitLab was in downtime. Let's try again and share information.

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same problem
my solution is - change username to email
by some reason gitlab doesn't search commits with filter: 
.../commits/master?author=Author Name
but .../commits/master?author=authorsEmail@org.com works